# Not able to connect BSNL evdo Prithvi in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers

i am not able to run BSNL prithvi evdo card in Ubuntu 13.04.
Can you please tell me how to fix  this ?

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The BNSL EVDO does not work by default for me too. I use it through gnome-ppp/wvdial. Please see if this helps:

Install gnome-ppp.
Run it as super user.
Give your 10 digit account-number as username AND password.
Give    Phone number as #777.
Click on 'Setup'
In the 'Modem' tab, click 'Detect'. The device gets detected as dev/ttyACM0.
In the 'Options' tab, along with the default options, also enable 'Ignore Terminal Strings (Stupid Mode)'.
Close the 'Setup' and try connecting now.

Also, before connecting, make sure the Modem is up. It usually takes about 30 seconds and the light stops blinking when the device is ready.